# I need to connect to sql server which i present in location such as 192.168.1.1 from my localhost

Tags: sql, grails, ssh

I need to connect to SQL server which I present in locations such as 192.168.1.1 from my localhost I was able to connect to the above server in MySql workbench using ssh tunneling. Can anyone help me on how do I do it in grail.

Answer (score 0):

Same way... [Set up the tunnel as before](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/133/Tunnel+local+MySQL+server+through+SSH) and [point grails to it](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-ssh):

```
# Configure SSH and SCP by adding properties to grails-app/conf/Config.groovy under the "remotessh" key:
# Option set a global username to access ssh through to remote host
# If you are going to define user from above commands then leave it with empty speach marks
remotessh.USER = "USER"
# The password leave blank if you are about to use SSH Keys, otherwise provide password to ssh auth
remotessh.PASS=""

# The ssh key is your id_rsa or id_dsa - please note your tomcat will need access/permissions to file/location
remotessh.KEY="/home/youruser/.ssh/id_rsa"

# If you use a key pass for your key connections then provide it below
remotessh.KEYPASS=""

# The ssh port to connect through if not given will default to 56022
remotessh.PORT="56022" # the forwarded port

# Hostname will default to localhost
```